# Play framework + IntelliJ: Project type changes when adding dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, elasticsearch, sbt, elastic4s

I'm writing a Play framework application and would like to use ElasticSearch to index and search data. The application is simple and I created it using IntelliJ > New Play Application, and so on.

Everything went well until I added

```
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.3.2",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s" % "1.3.2",
```

To `build.sbt`, which now looks like:

```
name := "example-core"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `example-core` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc ,
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
  anorm ,
  cache ,
  javaWs ,
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.3.2",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s" % "1.3.2"
)

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

Which is nothing fancy. As soon as I do that, IntelliJ fetches these plugins and somehow, changes my application type (correct me if I'm wrong) and from that point onwards, I can no longer add scala classes to packages: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk3o1x3n4ol5l0v/Screenshot%202014-12-01%2017.03.48.png?dl=0)

And this is how the same menu looks as soon as I remove

```
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.3.2",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s" % "1.3.2",
```

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1mo83uep3pjvwm/Screenshot%202014-12-01%2017.10.36.png?dl=0)

What is going on?

Comment: It can't be anything to do with adding those deps. How are you importing into intellij, using the import project option from the file menu and choosing SBT? If not, try that.

Comment: @monkjack looked more like an IntelliJ issue. I was manually adding the dependencies to 'build.sbt' and that didn't seem to work.